# Record exists in both tables but disappears with the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The following tables have the record "FF Studios" but when I run the query, I do not see any record.

```
Select *
from ( Select Name,
              Ref_name,
              Final_Name = CASE
                           WHEN _Similarity >=0.80
                            and _Match ='Solid Matched'
                            and Owner IS NOT NULL
                           THEN Ref_Name
                           ELSE Name
                           END, 
              Address,
              City,
              Province,
              [Postal Code],
              Country,
              Phone,
              Fax,
              Owner
              _Similarity,
              _Match
       from Customer_Stage3
     ) as a
WHERE a.Final_Name LIKE ('%FF St%')
  and ( a.Final_Name IN ( Select Customer_Clean 
                          from SFCustomerMerge 
                          Group BY Customer_Clean 
                          HAVING COUNT(Customer_Clean) > 1
                        ) 
      )
order by a._Similarity
```

In this case, the record exists within the SFCustomerMerge Table and Customer Stage 3, but when I add the the first Where clause it disappears and I have checked the Query

```
Select Customer_Clean
from SFCustomerMerge 
Group BY Customer_Clean 
HAVING COUNT(Customer_Clean) > 1
```

And the record appears in there too.

What am I missing? I also know the Similarity for this record is 0.98, match is Solid Matched and Owner is not NULL.

Comment: Maybe the owner is not `null` but an empty string? Try `IsNull(owner, '') != ''`. Or some kind of case sensitive problem with `a.Final_Name`and `Customer_Clean`?

Comment: I've double checked that as well. If I change the AND to an OR it works and I see the result. So this led me to think there was something with the Inner query Select Customer_Clean... but I do see the result there as well.

Comment: Or the name is not exactly the same.  There might be non-standard characters in the name, for instance.  You can use `ASCII()` to see the ascii values of the characters.

Comment: They are the same. Is there something wrong with the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the extra parenthesis in the WHERE clause? Did you try:

```
WHERE a.Final_Name IN (SELECT Customer_Clean
                       FROM SFCustomerMerge
                       GROUP BY Customer_Clean
                       HAVING COUNT(Customer_Clean) > 1)
```

Everything else looks fine, so that's the only thing I can see that might cause it.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the collation sequence(s) in use. case-sensitivity might be coming into play here. Further...how about embedded whitespace? Is it exactly the same?

However, for performance reasons, I would probably refactor your query to something like this:

```
select cs3.Name,
       cs3.Ref_name,
       cs3.Final_Name = case
                          when _Similarity >=0.80
                           and _Match ='Solid Matched'
                           and Owner IS NOT NULL
                          then Ref_Name
                          else Name
                        end, 
       cs3.Address,
       cs3.City,
       cs3.Province,
       cs3.[Postal Code],
       cs3.Country,
       cs3.Phone,
       cs3.Fax,
       cs3.Owner
       cs3._Similarity,
       cs3._Match
from Customer_State3 cs3
join ( Select cm.Customer_Clean 
       from SFCustomerMerge cm
       where cm.Customer_Clean like '%FF St%'
       Group BY cm.Customer_Clean 
       HAVING COUNT( cm.Customer_Clean ) > 1
     ) dupes on dupes.Customer_Clean = case
                                         when cs3._Similarity >= 0.80
                                          and cs3._Match       = 'Solid Matched'
                                          and cs3.Owner        is not NULL
                                         then cs3.Ref_Name
                                         else cs3.Name
                                       end = dupes.Customer_Clean
order by cs3._Similarity
```